# Use AudioKit Sequencer with Soundfont

Tags: swift, audiokit

I've been playing around with AudioKit for an app I'm building.

So far I've managed to trigger a sequence of midiNotes using AKSequencer but I would like to add a soundfont to be able to play actual piano sounds.

I tried a few things I found on the internet but no luck so far. Is anyone able to give me some steps on what I'd have to do?

Here's what I have so far:
https://gist.github.com/davidfloegel/056b870eb89416da267882172947af59

Thanks
David